# Load a file automatically without using a click button

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and want to load the file without having to click on the load file button

I am using the following script and I want the text to be loaded automatically in the text box.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Select a File to Load:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" id="fileToLoad">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load File</button>
                <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <textarea id="inputTextToSave" style="width:512px;height:256px"></textarea>
                </td></tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function loadFileAsText()
{
    var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the `onchange` attribute, this will call functions when changes have been made to that input.

```
<input type="file" id="fileToLoad" onchange="loadFileAsText()">
```

> **Demo**

```js
function loadFileAsText(){
var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent){ 
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
    };
fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
```

```html
<table><tr>
<td>Select a File to Load:</td>
<td><input type="file" id="fileToLoad" onchange="loadFileAsText()"></td>
                                 <!-- ^^ onchange attribute added ^^ -->
</tr><tr>
<td colspan="2"><textarea id="inputTextToSave" style="width:512px;height:256px"></textarea></td>
</tr></table>
```

If you have any questions about the above source code please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Absolutely Great. Thanks a lot... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the function on it's own like this:

```
loadFileAsText();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, I still don't know what to do. Can you modify the code...

Comment: Just add this to your script file `window.onload = loadFileAsText;`

Comment: Thanks. @TurboTech. I am sure something would have to be removed from the code as well.. I am not sure

Comment: Why would you want to run the function once the page has loaded? The input will be empty since the client hasn't selected a file...

Comment: Not sure what that means @NewToJS . The client has selected a file by choosing the file by pressing "Choose file" button. I am trying to load an existing file, and then modify the file after getting some inputs through 6 radio buttons. Now the code contains a "Load button" for loading the file which I want to eliminate.

Comment: ok i see what you mean. @manju's [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jage0e48/1/) seems to have what your looking for. You can use that as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Javascript events. for ex: you can call like below:

```
<input type="file" id="fileToLoad" onblur="loadFileAsText()">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Manju. Since I am new to javascript, how would the exact code look like. If you can help...

Comment: I just went through your code, basically you are trying to read file data and display it. however the loadFileAsText() function is not doing that yet.

Comment: check the exact code which i put in https://jsfiddle.net/jage0e48/1/ to read file data and display it

Comment: Thanks for the understanding. Possibly you can help too.

Comment: you can read more about file operations in http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ and if the above code worked for you, can you please mark it as answered?

Comment: Just went through the post @Manju But the solution you have given still adds another button called "entire file". I want to avoid clicking on a new button entirely. Can't it be like the  moment I choose a file it is directly loaded into the text box?

Answer (score 0):

Respond to the document's `ready` event:

```
$(document).ready( loadFileAsText );
```

If you don't want to use jQuery for simple compatibility with multiple browsers, then see this answer:  [pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/1172714)